# Graphics tablet shows up in evtest, but not in xinput

Tags: drivers, xinput, graphics-tablet

I got my brand-new Huion H430P tablet delivered today, and paid attention to the availability of Linux drivers when buying it in the first place. I installed [digimend-kernel-drivers](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers) (v9) and it seems that the tablet is recognized as a USB device, but is not able to draw in any of the programs I tried. (OS: Kubuntu 18.04)

Going through the ["How to locate a failure"](http://digimend.github.io/support/howto/trbl/locating_failure/) instructions on the Digimend project site, I tracked down a possible issue: The graphics tablet is listed when executing `sudo evtest` (and the test itself seems to work as well on first sight), but not in `xinput list`.

Unfortunately I'm very much not an expert with drivers, but does this give any indication on what I could fix to get the tablet running?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I solved it without installing any additional drivers, the trick was to update de xinput devices manually.

This is what I did:

## Find out what the USB id assigned to the tablet.

- Ensure that the tablet is **not** connected.
- Execute a

  ```
  lsusb
  ```
- Save the results somewhere.
- Connect the tablet
- Execute again

  ```
  lsusb
  ```
- The new value would be the USB id for the tablet.

## Edit the X server config file

- Change directory to

  ```
  /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
  ```
- Create a file ( using sudo ) named

  ```
  50-tablet.conf
  ```

  for example
- Fill it with a content similar to

  ```
  Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "Tablet"
  Driver "wacom"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  MatchUSBID "abcd:zyxw"
  EndSection
  ```
- abcd:zyxw is the USB code that was previously discovered.
- Reboot

## Error log

You may find an error log on

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

## Sample Steps

This is an almost actual log from my machine

```
$ uname -a 
Linux fakeLaptop 4.15.0-118-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 8 12:30:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- No tablet connected

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:57f2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

- Connected tablet

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:57f2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 256c:006d   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

- The id is **256c:006d**

```
$ cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d 
$ cat 50-tablet.conf 
Section "InputClass" 
    Identifier "Tablet" 
    Driver "wacom" 
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" 
     MatchUSBID "256c:006d" 
EndSection 
$
```

Hope it helps!