# View raw stylus input?

Tags: command-line, xorg, hp, touchscreen, stylus

I have an HP Spectre x360 laptop with a touchscreen, that also has an HP stylus for input. Currently, the stylus isn't working, i.e. I touch it to the screen but it doesn't move the cursor, cause clicks, etc. The touchscreen works fine for finger touches.

I'm wondering if there's a command that will show raw inputs from the touchscreen/stylus, so that I can whether the problem is that the inputs aren't being interpreted properly, or that it's not receiving input at all?

Comment: As part of your investigation, run `xinput` and see if something like "ELAN Touchscreen Pen" is present. It should be separate from the "ELAN Touchscreen" input.

Answer (score 0):

Use [xinput](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xinput) in a terminal window to find the stylus device; e.g.,

```
    $ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen Pen                      id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

You can then use `xinput test-xi2 <device-ID>` to display raw input for that device (or skip the device to display all events); e.g.,

```
$ xinput test-xi2 9
ELAN Touchscreen Pen                            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
        Reporting 4 classes:
                Class originated from: 9. Type: XIButtonClass
                Buttons supported: 7
                Button labels: "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right"
                Button state:
                Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
                Detail for Valuator 0:
                Label: Abs X
                Range: 0.000000 - 32256.000000
                Resolution: 110000 units/m
                Mode: absolute
                Current value: 1280.000000
                Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
                Detail for Valuator 1:
                Label: Abs Y
                Range: 0.000000 - 17920.000000
                Resolution: 108000 units/m
                Mode: absolute
                Current value: 720.000000
                Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
                Detail for Valuator 2:
                Label: Abs Pressure
                Range: 0.000000 - 255.000000
                Resolution: 0 units/m
                Mode: absolute
                Current value: 0.000000
```

You can exit the event display with Ctrl+C.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have ELAN Touchscreen Pen on mine, so maybe there is a device detection problem...

Comment: So I guess that means the problem is the device is not available/detected. If you can't find a solution to that, it would probably make sense to post as a different question. Make sure to include more details about your system, OS version etc. And btw, my condolences on having bought an HP Spectre...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [evtest](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/evtest.1.html):

```shell
sudo evtest
```

Sometimes if your device does not appear in xinput, you can find it in evtest. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241381/graphics-tablet-shows-up-in-evtest-but-not-in-xinput).